# exporting a report to excel from lightswitch and trying to create a border in excel

Tags: excel, vb.net-2010, visual-studio-lightswitch

I been trying to create a border in excel using light switch. I created the document no problem and am able to format the document however I want. However when it come to putting the excel border on the excel I cannot seem to get it right

```
**Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices.Automation
Imports System.Collections.Specialized**
 **With excel.Range("A5:M6")
                    .Borders(excel.XlBordersIndex.xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
                End With**
```

There is the code I using and above it is the referances as I say eveything is fine baring the creation of the borders. The system does not like XlBordersIndex "Error while invoking XlBordersIndex - member not found." is there something I need to referance I been googleing from quite some time and cannot find anything for Microsoft Light Switch

Comment: Tried it and got this error is there something I missing.Warning 1 Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.Automation.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlInsideVertical' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases. C:\WebApplication35\DebtCounsolesystem\DebtCounsolesystem\Client\UserCode\CreateCustomers.vb 6 9 Client

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `excel` is the name of a variable -- an `Application`, a `Worksheet` or something else which has a `Range` property -- which conflicts with the `Excel` namespace. Perhaps try one of the following:

- rename the `excel` variable to something else
- reference the `XlBordersIndex` enumeration by `Excel` (with a capital E).
- reference the enumeration by the full namespace: `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Automation.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlInsideVertical`